# Ошибка при удалении инвайтов discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я не могу удалить инвайты с сервера этим кодом

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands

import config

class InvitesCmd(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client: nextcord.Client = client


    @commands.command(aliases=config.RESTORE_INVITES_CMD)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def __invites_restore(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        invite_list: list = await ctx.guild.invites()
        for invite in invite_list:
            await invite.delete()
```

Он вызывает ошибку

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 165, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Ilya\Разные файлы\bot\cmds\invites_cmd.py", line 16, in __invites_restore
    await invite.delete()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\invite.py", line 511, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_invite(self.code, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\http.py", line 331, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 7288fb3ce80dc41f &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-07-10 11:32:53 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>

          </div>


      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">7288fb3ce80dc41f</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">31.134.188.97</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

<script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7288fb3ce80dc41f',m:'7AFrEtg4QaNdx4CHUgTPFIHyx.FtSxRwFcvYxNSGRK4-1657452773-0-AdBE8cozMvwcXzu/DGoupV/q9XBZ0WrCtoBBGNiAd2r0NVlfDNI8rnn0rUt73ff2mTFMUqH7fMCtaLeHz36xrVd52bZ2QHB3dgdzbw2EvWC1K9E8qAGt3a4Kbo/wMrKQRUq64fdxh8uspJiEgeQFE4o=',s:[0x2441d8f4d2,0x899d142da2],}})();</script></body>
</html>


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1117, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 948, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 174, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/669835187/api.js'></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 7288fb3ce80dc41f &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-07-10 11:32:53 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>

          </div>


      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">7288fb3ce80dc41f</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">31.134.188.97</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

<script>(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7288fb3ce80dc41f',m:'7AFrEtg4QaNdx4CHUgTPFIHyx.FtSxRwFcvYxNSGRK4-1657452773-0-AdBE8cozMvwcXzu/DGoupV/q9XBZ0WrCtoBBGNiAd2r0NVlfDNI8rnn0rUt73ff2mTFMUqH7fMCtaLeHz36xrVd52bZ2QHB3dgdzbw2EvWC1K9E8qAGt3a4Kbo/wMrKQRUq64fdxh8uspJiEgeQFE4o=',s:[0x2441d8f4d2,0x899d142da2],}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

Помоите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вот у вас есть `class InvitesCmd`, а где в коде создание экземпляра этого класса? Я не вижу, чтобы он где-то запускался — это первое. Второе — вы уверены, что для решения одной конкретной задачи стоит использовать классы и `discord.ext.commands.Cog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил эту проблему меня временно по ip забанили